# JMeter Cookie Manager not sending / passing certain cookie

Tags: jmeter, cookiemanager

I am extracting cookies from the previous HTTP Requests and then passing onto subsequent requests. Except 2 cookies everything else passed successfully. An idea what else I could do to make this work?

[image: CookieManager]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What characters you deleted from image? Is it non english characters   ?

Answer (score 1):

My expectation is that `standard` cookie policy requires "Domain" field presence, moreover it needs to match the URL of the [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler,

So options are in:

- Populate `Domain` field with the hostname of the application under test
- Play with `Cookie Policy` dropdown value, i.e. you could try changing policy to `netscape` which is less "strict"

However you are not supposed to add cookies manually, HTTP Cookie Manager should automatically handle the cookies. See [HTTP Cookie Manager Advanced Usage - A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-cookie-manager-advanced-usage-a-guide) article for more information on Cookie Manager configuration and troubleshooting if needed.